# Error when adding element to ListOfMap in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I'm using List of Map in java but I get a trouble. I use :

`Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
 ArrayList<Map<String,AttributeValue>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String,AttributeValue>>();`

I use CSVReader to reading file and store values in ListOfMap

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data1.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    item.clear();
    item.put("Id", new AttributeValue().withN(nextLine[0]));
    item.put("Name", new AttributeValue().withS(nextLine[1]));

    System.out.println("Item:"+item); // I try printing item
    maps.add(item);
    }
```

And Result is :

```
    Item:{Id={N: 0,}, Name={S: goGOv,}}
    Item:{Id={N: 1,}, Name={S: TBlGD,}}
    Item:{Id={N: 2,}, Name={S: OtXuw,}}
    ...
    Item:{Id={N: 999,}, Name={S: QAMzc,}}
    Item:{Id={N: 1000,}, Name={S: PumAq,}}
```

But when I print some element from this List

```
System.out.println(" "+maps.get(i)); // I tried i from 0-1000
```

It always show only 1 ouput

```
{Id={N: 1000,}, Name={S: PumAq,}}
```

So anyone can show me where I'm wrong.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same map to store all elements, but at start of each iteration you are calling `item.clear();` which removes previously stored elements inside map. What you should do is create new, separate map instead of reusing old one, so change

```
item.clear();//don't reuse previously filled map because it still is the same map
```

into

```
item = new HashMap<>();//use separate map
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep using the same Map object. These are persistant objects. You'll have to instantiate a new HashMap() instead of calling clear() on the existing one.

Otherwise you'll simply clear the HashMap inside of the List as well, because they refer to the same object.